# Cannot Connect to Mssql database using PHP on shared Namecheap server

Tags: php, sql-server, shared-hosting, namecheap

I am trying to connect to a mssql database hosted on a different website than the one I am connecting from. The basic syntax of my code is

```
$db = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password);
```

and I get the error

```
Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: *ip* in *filename* on line 41
```

I am using a Namecheap shared hosting account to host my site. I had to go into the php config to enable the mssql module.

According to [this](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1249/89/how-to-remotely-connect-to-mysql-database-located-on-our-shared-server) Namecheap support page

> Remote MySQL connection is disabled on our shared servers due to security reasons

So my question is is my error due specifically to my site being on shared servers? Is that quote referring to connections going out from the host, or does it mean connections coming in? I would think that it wouldn't let me use the Mssql module at all on the shared servers if it was literally impossible to use it.

Comment: Title says `mssql`, error says `mysql`. What DB are you using? I highly doubt a free provider would give mssql access. That's very pricey.

Comment: If you are running the script on the same server as the db you should be good. You should use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` for *ip* in that case, not your servers IP visible from the outside.
The only thing not working will be running the db on their servers and connect to that db from another server.

Comment: I am using paid hosting on shared servers. The remote database is mssql and is already set up on a different website. I just need to connect to it through php. That support page says MySQL which is not the database I am worried about, but I thought the bit about remote connections being disabled might be important.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the connection issue is due to NameCheap's block of mysql. You can check the logs [MySql log man page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log.html) for more information about your MySql errors. If they are blocking it, there's no amount of PHP code you can write to overcome this. NameCheap has great customer support, you can do a live chat to ask them.

Comment: well there is way to get around this, create a small php program in the Namecheap server that will forward the request.  That's horribly slow and can even open you to direct attacks.